# how to control users login on Linux machine according to configuration file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, authentication, sshd

I use the PAM to authenticate users login

info from -  http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_listfile

in my Linux red-hat machine I have 5 diff users

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
user5
```

I want to enable ssh login only to the first three users

so

I created the file

```
more /etc/logins_users.txt

user1
user2
user3
```

and I add to **/etc/pam.d/sshd** file the following

```
   auth required pam_listfile.so item=user onerr=fail sense=allow file=/etc/logins_user.txt
```

I restart the sshd service

but **user4** and **user5** are still have access to the linux machine in spite they not defined in the logins_users.txt file

What is wrong with my configuration?

Why **user4** and **user5** still have ssh login access in spite they are blocked???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your configuration.

Write your configuration in first line of `/etc/pam.d/sshd` like this

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required     pam_listfile.so item=user onerr=fail sense=allow file=/etc/logins_user.txt
auth       required     pam_sepermit.so
auth       include      password-auth
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
```

That is because PAM will check all these configuration line by line , if you put your configuration in last line then any other condition will pass before checking your condition , That's why all users all able to login . Check this and let me know.

**Be careful while trying this**

Before changing anything take a backup of file.

if you configure like this

```
auth       required     pam_listfile.so item=user onerr=fail sense=allow file=/etc/logins_user.txt
auth       include      password-auth
account    required     pam_nologin.so
.
.
session    include      password-auth
```

And condition fails still PAM will check remaing rules.

if you configure like this

```
auth       requisite    pam_listfile.so item=user onerr=fail sense=allow file=/etc/logins_user.txt
auth       include      password-auth
account    required     pam_nologin.so
.
.
session    include      password-auth
```

And above condition fails , PAM will not check remaing rules.

required

```
Failure also results in denial of authentication, although PAM will still call all the other modules listed for this service before denying authentication.
```

requisite

```
Failure to authenticate via this module results in immediate denial of authentication.
```

So in your case may be below condition giving permission

```
auth       include      password-auth
```

You are entering correct password while ssh.